# OpenGL, C++ I keep getting error: 'int main(int, char**)' previously defined here in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I don't have a duplicate main statement but I keep getting a error: 'int main(int, char**)' previously defined here in C++

```
#include <GL/freeglut.h>

void displayGraphics()
{
    glClearColor(0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f, 1.0f);   // Makes buffer clear light gray and opaque
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Begin Hexagon
    // Quadrant 1
    glColor3f(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f);    // Orange
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(0.5f, 1.0f);
    glVertex2f(1.0f, 0.637f);
    glVertex2f(0.809f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.191f, 0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, 0.637f);
    glEnd();
    // End Hexagon
    // Begin Septagon
    // Quadrant II
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.1f, 0.5f, 0.0f);    // Dark Green
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, 1.0f);    // 1st Vertex
    glVertex2f(-0.1f, 0.8f);    // 2nd Vertex
    glVertex2f(-0.0f, 0.4f);    // 3rd Vertex
    glVertex2f(-0.25f, 0.0f);   // 4th Vertex
    glVertex2f(-0.75f, 0.0f);   // 5th Vertex
    glVertex2f(-1.0f, 0.4f);    // 6th Vertex
    glVertex2f(-0.9f, 0.8f);    // 7th Vertex
    glEnd();
    // End Septagon
    // Begin Star
    /* Using a downwards facing triangle and an upwards
    facing arrow shape to draw the star */
    // Quadrant III and IV
    // Draw Upward Facing Arrow Shape
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3f(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.7f);        // Dark blue
    glVertex2f(0.0f, -0.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.309f, -1.0f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, -0.763f);
    glVertex2f(-0.309f, -1.0f);
    glEnd();
    // Draw Downward Facing Triangle Shape
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glVertex2f(0.5f, -0.4f);
    glVertex2f(0.0f, -0.763f);
    glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.4f);
    glEnd();
    // End Star
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);      // Initialize the freeglut library
    glutCreateWindow("2D Shapes");
    glutInitWindowSize(1600, 1600); // Set default window size
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);   // Set default window position
    glutDisplayFunc(displayGraphics);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

the error is

```
C:/TDM-GCC-64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/include/GL/freeglut.h:87:5: note: 'int main(int, char**)' previously defined here
   87 | int main(int argc, char** argv){
```

I don't have a duplicate main statement.  This is occuring for all of my code.

Comment: Can you please post the command you are using to compile your program?

Comment: That header has [almost nothing in it](https://github.com/dcnieho/FreeGLUT/blob/git_master/freeglut/freeglut/include/GL/freeglut.h)—did you overwrite it somehow?